# How to extract complete matching word in R string

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have strings as below.
I want to extract `cnn` and `cnncod40` (as example but i have hundreds of these values like `cnn` and `cnncod40` but with different names) using stringer but it gives me only `cnn`. How to extract both `cnn` and `cnncod40`.

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c('strng_tst_1_cnn_rst.txt', 'strng_tst_1_cnncod40_cst.txt','strng_tst_2_cnn_crst.txt', 'strng_tst_2_cnncod40_rrst.txt')

ind_val <- c('cnn','cnncod40') # i have hundreds of ind_val so need a pattern to use `ind_val`
str_extract(strings, paste(ind_val , collapse = "|"))
```

Output is `"cnn" "cnn" "cnn" "cnn"` but i want `'cnn','cnncod40','cnn','cnncod40'`

Comment: Would it be also sufficient to grab the pattern between the last occurence or `"_"` and the first occurence of `".txt"`.

Comment: `str_extract(strings, paste(ind_val[order(-nchar(ind_val))] , collapse = "|"))` should work in all your cases

Answer (score 0):

You ca use `sub` with no extra package

```
> sub( ".*(cnn|cnncod40).*", "\\1", strings)
[1] "cnn"      "cnncod40" "cnn"      "cnncod40"
```

If you put the pattern in the other way around it will work

```
str_extract_all(strings, "cnncod40|cnn")
```

**Edit**

Using `paste` to create a pattern with hundreds of elements:

```
ind_val <- c('cnn','cnncod40')
big_pattern <- paste0(".*(", paste(ind_val , collapse = "|"),").*")
sub(big_pattern, "\\1", strings)
[1] "cnn"      "cnncod40" "cnn"      "cnncod40"
```

Comment: Ho you use sub with the pattern when you have a large vectors of ind_val ? See modified question.

Comment: why not use word boundaries ie `\b`?